# Visual Studios 2010 - Asp.net MVC 4 Beta - long delays on paste and frequent crashing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

Hey fellow developers,

**Disclaimer:** 
- Before this gets flagged to high heaven, I realize the asp.net mvc 4 release is Beta, and I don't expect perfection, but the release is brand new, so there's really just not much user info out (that I could find) discussing IDE issues.

**The issue:** 
I installed the Asp.net MVC 4 Beta and it's great. However I am experiencing like 15-20 second delays on pasting anything anywhere, (not cutting, not copying, not formatting just pasting)

Also I am getting rather frequent crashes, somewhat intermittenly.

****Edit: All add in's and extensions have been disabled **** 
I am running resharper 5 and stylecop, all other add ins I have disabled.

Is anyone out there experiencing similar issues? and does anyone by chance have any idea on a known settings issue or a work around or anything. It's very hard to use right now when ever copy paste results in a huge lag spike.

Comment: Do you experience the same issues when Resharper and StyleCop are disabled?

Comment: yup, i added an edit above to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same thing is happening to me.  Long delays between copy/paste, however I DO NOT have an encrypted HD..so I do not think that is it.

I have tried a new application and one that I created from the previous MVC 4 Beta and it happens in both.  So, its not the upgrade to the new MVC4 Beta.

EDIT:  MICROSOFT IS AWARE OF THE ISSUE:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2012/02/27/vs2010-sp1-mvc4-beta-workaround-for-cshtml-vbhtml-editor-s-long-pause.aspx

Workaround is to build the assemblies and have them in the bin folder.

EDIT 2 2/29/2012: This is happening in Visual Studio 11 Beta.  Looks like this is an ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta problem.

EDIT 3 03/07/2012:  Here is the workaround of Visual Studio 11...http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2012/03/06/visual-studio-11-beta-razor-editor-issue-workaround.aspx

EDIT 4 11/02/2012: This is fixed in Visual Studio 2012 RTM

Comment: Is this fixed yet for Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar issue. It was only happening when I was editing .cshtml files, but only on a newly created project.

If I create a new MVC4 application using Razor, and then immediately open **_Layout.cshtml** for example, any attempt to cut and paste a line (or comment a line using *CTRL+K+C*) results in a wait of about 40 seconds for me. However, if I do a rebuild, the editing then works fine for all files from that point forward.