# How to improve VS 2012 editor performance for WPF, C# application

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, visual-studio-2012

I am working on VS 2012 and sometimes its really painful. I know that I can improve the speed  by changing some settings in VS editor but actually I don't know which setting is that. Can you please suggest me those settings which can improve my development speed?

Comment: Use/Try Blend instead!

Comment: Blend can replace VS 2012? I have always used Blend for dissecting/ changing WPF controls . Are you sure?

Comment: Try _Tools > Import and Export Settings... > Reset all settings._ Check this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/12694912/674700](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12694912/674700).

Comment: The best solution I have found is to re-install VS2010

Comment: Do you have any add-ins installed?

Comment: @MatthewWatson, there is no add-in in add-in manager.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do [this suggestions](http://blog.geocortex.com/2007/12/07/slow-visual-studio-performance-solved/)

> Go to OPTIONS>ENVIRONMENT..under Visual Experience, untick “Use
>   Hardware Graphics Acceleration If Available”
>
> “Tools”-”Options”-”Enviroments and Updates” and disable “Automatically
>   Check for Updates