# Visual Studio 2012 Express Hangs with Message "Waiting for Background Operation to Complete" on Format Document Command

Tags: visual-studio-2012

This just started a couple of days ago. Every time I format a document with Ctrl + K + D, VS hangs and displays that message. Seems like for some reason it's just taking a ridiculously long time to run the format command (20 seconds or so, sometimes longer on larger documents).

Didn't install any new add-ins (don't really have any installed at all). I followed all of the suggestions in this post: [What is this 'Waiting for Background operation' in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175784/what-is-this-waiting-for-background-operation-in-visual-studio-2012) which seems to have solved the issue for some but they didn't help. I've seen some similar posts around the web but haven't been able to find anything that works.

Running VS 2012 Express on Windows 8.

Anybody else getting this or have any idea what might be causing it?

**EDIT** - Was also seeing a lot of issues during cut, copy, and paste operations.

**EDIT #2** - I know this question is a bit old but it's been getting a little traction lately and I saw that it was marked as a duplicate for [What is this 'Waiting for Background operation' in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175784/what-is-this-waiting-for-background-operation-in-visual-studio-2012) but it absolutely is not. This problem was linked to two specific actions on the user's part where the "duplicate" was said to not be related to anything specifically. The other question also talks about plugins that were not installed, and an entirely different version of the application. Additionally, none of the solutions recommended (or the accepted answer) solved the problem, so they're certainly not duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why this wouldn't be a more-widespread issue but I seem to have found a (temporary?) solution. (Note - I continued to have this issue even after installing Update 2.) For now, the issue seems to be resolved by running VS as an administrator. Doesn't seem like it should be the permanent solution but it's working for the time-being.

**EDIT** - This also fixed issues I was having with some source control operations taking extremely long, as well as projects opening very slowly.