# Visual Studio Template Creating Multiple Solution Files

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, templates

I am creating a solution template (containing 4 projects) for Visual Studio 2022 using a template.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
  "author": "Me",
  "classifications": [ "Web", "Solution", "Web API" ],
  "defaultName": "WebTemplate",
  "icon":"icon.png",
  "identity": "vanguardWebApiTemplate",
  "name": "Vanguard Web Api Template",
  "shortName": "vanguardWebApiTemplate",
  "sourceName": "Vanguard.WebApiTemplate",
  "preferNameDirectory": true,
  "tags": {
    "language": "C#",
    "type": "solution"
  },
  "guids": [
    "E17122AE-2E52-459D-885A-EDBE3BD43B34",
    "D99C062B-E50F-4F47-A055-7D1005C039A1",
    "340C19B1-D448-435D-A46E-E6C907921EE8",
    "92812E59-FD1F-4C70-B949-4224849DC6D1"
  ],
  "symbols": {
      "ServiceName": {
          "type": "parameter",
          "dataType": "string",
          "replaces": "ServiceName",
          "description": "The PascalCase name of the service.",
          "isRequired": "true",
      }
  }
}
```

I can successfully install the Visual Studio template with Powershell

```
dotnet new --install C:\<path to template>\Vanguard.WebApiTemplate\
```

When I create a new solution using my template, Visual Studio 2022 hangs during the **Creating Project...** dialog and eventually crashes. However, it does create all the files I expect to be contained in the template, but it creates two different copies of the .sln file (notice the different file size).

[image: Duplicate Solution File]

Any ideas why Visual Studio hangs/crashes and why two different .sln files are generated?

Comment: There is one `, ` after "isRequired": "true".   Does the problem happen every time?

Comment: I believe the issue is related to uninstalling and re-installing the template.

I run: dotnet new --uninstall C:\<path to template>\Vanguard.WebApiTemplate\

and then delete my %USERPROFILE%/.templateengine directory but when I go to re-install the template, using a new name, the old name still shows up. It seems like Visual Studio is doing some broken caching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was caused by ReSharper. I disabled it and now Visual Studio can create my multi-project solution.

See this related post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46319242/14134046

Answer (score 0):

Did `dotnet new --uninstall` return successful?

Here is [a  thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/714454/location-of-visual-studio-2022-project-template-ca)   describing where to find the cache.

> %appdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio<the version of visual studio,
> 16.0_4810b0af, 17.0_e97c61af, etc>\ItemTemplatesCache and ProjectTemplatesCache
>
> %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio<the version of visual studio,
> 16., 17., etc>
>
> In those directories, locate and delete InstalledTemplates.json.

Try deleting the cache.

Comment: Yes the dotnet new --uninstall returns successfully. I deleted the caches at these locations, as well as the %USERPROFILE%\.templateengine folder. After re-installing my template I am still experiencing the same problem where VS hangs and creates 2 .sln files.

Comment: I think anti-virus software is interfering with Visual Studio's ability to create the solution... I'm investigating