# TFS: Compare with Workspace Version shows blank screen

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015

When I click on "Compare with Workspace Version" in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, using TFS, I get a blank screen with a message at the bottom saying "Running a compare operation in the background. Once the operation has completed, the results will be displayed in the compare tool."

I restarted my machine and also went into the following cache folders and cleared out the contents:

```
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\TFSTemp

C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache
```

Strangely, when I do a solution-wide search for a term, some of the cached items in that first path still appear in the search results, and the files open even though I deleted them.

I suspect that a slow internet connection is related to the issue, but I can't compare any files now, even with the internet being at tolerable speeds.  Is there more cache I can clear to get the compare feature working again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the option to reset all settings as per the following thread, and compare started working again:

[What is this 'Waiting for Background operation' in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175784/what-is-this-waiting-for-background-operation-in-visual-studio-2012)